# GWT Customize CellList Multi-Selection Model for Mobile Devices

Tags: gwt, overriding, gwt-2.2-celltable, multipleselection

I have an application, that uses the MultiSelectionModel, and it works great, but I need the site I'm developing to work on mobile devices, and so I can't use the keyboard to assist in selecting the elements (since it doesn't exist).  EX: On the desktop I just hold ctrl and click on all the element that I want to select.

So on the mobile device, I would like to modify the default behavior of the MultiSelectionModel so that when you click on a CellList item, it toggles the selection state of that item.
I have looked through the source for it and cannot see anyway to implement the behavior that I need. (Mobile MultiSelection).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether you add a checkbox column or not, you'll have to [add a cell preview handler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractHasData.html#addCellPreviewHandler%28com.google.gwt.view.client.CellPreviewEvent.Handler%29). The easiest way to define one is to use [DefaultSelectionEventManager](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/view/client/DefaultSelectionEventManager.html), either using a [checkbox manager](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/view/client/DefaultSelectionEventManager.html#createCheckboxManager%28%29) in combination with a checkbox column, or [creating a custom one](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/view/client/DefaultSelectionEventManager.html#createCustomManager%28com.google.gwt.view.client.DefaultSelectionEventManager.EventTranslator%29) (you'd map a click event into a [toggle action](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/view/client/DefaultSelectionEventManager.SelectAction.html#TOGGLE)).

You can see it used, the checkbox variant, in the [GWT Showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable); it uses the `setSelectionModel` overload with two arguments to add the `CellPreviewEvent.Handler` at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I needed to use a CellList, so I brewed up the multi-selection functionality I needed from a SingleSelectionHandler.

Comment: Hey napo, I'm looking to implement toggle-on-click functionality with a CellList (not CellTable) also, can you share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just adding an extra checkbox column would be a more user friendly solution.