# GWT CellList Click to Toggle selection (Multi-Selection)

Tags: gwt, multi-select, gwt-2.2-celltable, gwt-2.4

I'd like to setup a CellList so that clicking a row will toggle the selection. Such that multiple rows can be selected with out the need for holding the ctrl key.

What do I need to change to get it working?

```
class ToggleEventTranslator<T> implements DefaultSelectionEventManager.EventTranslator<T> {
    @Override
    public boolean clearCurrentSelection(final CellPreviewEvent<T> event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public SelectAction translateSelectionEvent(final CellPreviewEvent<T> event) {
        return SelectAction.TOGGLE;
    }

}


MultiSelectionModel<ObjProxy> multiSelectionModel = new MultiSelectionModel<ObjProxy>();

    ocjCellList.setSelectionModel(multiSelectionModel, DefaultSelectionEventManager
            .<ObjProxy> createCustomManager(new ToggleEventTranslator<ObjProxy>()));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
list.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<T>() {

        @Override
        public void onCellPreview(final CellPreviewEvent<T> event) {

            if (BrowserEvents.CLICK.equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {

                final T value = event.getValue();
                final Boolean state = !event.getDisplay().getSelectionModel().isSelected(value);
                event.getDisplay().getSelectionModel().setSelected(value, state);
                event.setCanceled(true);
            }
        }
});


private final MultiSelectionModel<T> selectModel = new MultiSelectionModel<T>();

final Handler<T> selectionEventManager = DefaultSelectionEventManager.createCheckboxManager();
list.setSelectionModel(selectModel, selectionEventManager);
```

Comment: what does 'selectModel' definition look like?

Comment: I've tried this code with a CellList and it doesn't enable multiple items to be selected. Is there more to the implementation?

Comment: Good catch, using this selection model should enable multiple items to be selected.   private final MultiSelectionModel<T> selectModel = new MultiSelectionModel<T>();

Answer (score 3):

"Whether you add a checkbox column or not, you'll have to [add a cell preview handler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractHasData.html#addCellPreviewHandler%28com.google.gwt.view.client.CellPreviewEvent.Handler%29). The easiest way to define one is to use [DefaultSelectionEventManager](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/view/client/DefaultSelectionEventManager.html), either using a [checkbox manager](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/view/client/DefaultSelectionEventManager.html#createCheckboxManager%28%29) in combination with a checkbox column, or [creating a custom one](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/view/client/DefaultSelectionEventManager.html#createCustomManager%28com.google.gwt.view.client.DefaultSelectionEventManager.EventTranslator%29) (you'd map a click event into a [toggle action](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/view/client/DefaultSelectionEventManager.SelectAction.html#TOGGLE)).

You can see it used, the checkbox variant, in the [GWT Showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable); it uses the `setSelectionModel` overload with two arguments to add the `CellPreviewEvent.Handler` at the same time."

(Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847863/gwt-customize-celllist-multi-selection-model-for-mobile-devices/6852325#6852325))

Comment: Thanks for the post.  How does it apply to a CellList? Achieving Toggle-on-click behavior with a CellTable is straightforward, but I haven't been able to get it working with a CellList.